# Variable passed to each() is not an array

Tags: plugins, php

I have a plugin which throws the error "Warning: Variable passed to each() is not an array or object in /...../wp-content/plugins/page-scroll-to-id/malihu-pagescroll2id.php on line 174" and at line 174, it says

```
`   while(list($var, $val)=each($pl_instances)){
                add_settings_section(
                    $this->db_prefix.'settings_section'.$this->index,
                    null,
                    '__return_false', // instead of null to avoid wp <3.4.1 warnings (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21630)
                    $this->plugin_slug
                );`
```

The plugin is not modified, i did google on the error, but found nothing. I am new to php. so don't know much what's going in the code that is showing error.

Comment: `$pl_instances` is neither an array nor object. Where is that variable set?

Comment: @s_ha_dum how can I find it?

Comment: Look at the code until you see `$pl_instances = `

Comment: @s_ha_dum `$pl_instances=get_option($this->db_prefix.'instances', $this->default);`